# How to obtain all the tuples after a certain date in sql?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have to obtain the male employee with highest number of requests in the second half of April 2014.

I have these tables:

- Employee (EmployeeID, firstName, LastName, gender)
- Workplace (CompanyID, EmployeeID, CompanyName)
- Extras (ExtraID, CompanyID, Requests, Description, Date)

`Extras.Requests` is a string, not numerical.

My SQL attempt looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, 
    SUM(COUNT(Extras.ExtraID) 
FROM 
    Employee 
INNER JOIN
    (Workplace 
INNER JOIN 
    Extras ON Workplace.CompanyID = Extras.CompanyID) 
    ON Workplace.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID 
WHERE 
    Employee.Gender = "male" 
    AND Extras.Date BETWEEN #4/15/2014# AND #4/30/2014#
SORT BY 
    SUM(COUNT(Extras.ExtraID) DESC;
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm not sure if my query is correct or not, thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And store dates as dates

Comment: @strawberry you removed a nested join, thereby changing the question

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The question is tagged for both mysql & ms-access.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use. (Which is probably ms access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your query`SUM(COUNT(...))` nesting aggregate functions like this isn't permitted

You also need a `GROUP BY` clause to use aggregation function with **non-aggregating columns** (which are `Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName` in your query).

Sorting is performed by an `ORDER BY` clause

Your original query includes a nested inner join which is likely to produce unexpected results.

```
FROM Employee 
   INNER JOIN(Workplace 
   INNER JOIN Extras ON Workplace.CompanyID=Extras.CompanyID
             ) ON Workplace.EmployeeID=Employee.EmployeeID
```

While nesting joins is allowed it is rarely used, I suggest you avoid it.

I would expect the query to look more like this

```
SELECT
    Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, COUNT(Extras.ExtraID)
FROM ((Employee
    INNER JOIN Workplace
        ON Workplace.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID)
    INNER JOIN Extras
        ON Workplace.CompanyID = Extras.CompanyID)
WHERE Employee.Gender = "male"
    AND Extras.Date BETWEEN #4/15/2014# AND #4/30/2014#
GROUP BY
    Employee.FirstName
   ,Employee.LastName
ORDER BY
    COUNT(Extras.ExtraID) DESC;
LIMIT 1;
```

It's been years since I used access, I think it still wants parentheses in the from clause as I've shown above. In most SQL implementation they are not required, and it is more common for literals to use single quotes e.g. `WHERE Employee.Gender = 'male'`.